# System.text.json convert empty string to int

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json

Json.Net converted empty strings in ints/floats to 0 if there was an empty string. I'm using type numeric in my inputs, but empty fields will be an empty string in a form post call. Is there a config to convert empty strings to a Null or 0 like Json.net ?

fiddle below.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/CDNicW

Answer (score 0):

Just make value nullable

```
public class Model
    {
         [JsonNumberHandling(JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString)]
        public int? Value { get; set; }
    }
```

the result will be

```
{ value: null }
```

you will not be able to create your fiddler json in a real life

```
string json = "{\"Value\":\"\"}";
```

but if it is your scholl project, you can deserialize it using Newtonsoft.Json ( install the nuget package)

```
    Model d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(json);
    Console.WriteLine("Value: " + d.Value);
    string s =JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d);
    Console.WriteLine("json: " + s);
}
```

output

```
Value: 
json: {"Value":null}
```

but if you still want to uses Text.Json then you will have change Model class

```
public class Model
{
    private string _val;
    [JsonPropertyName("Value")]
    public string Val {

        get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(_val) ? null : _val; }
        set { _val = value;} 
    }

    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
    public int Value
    {
        get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(Val) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(Val); }
        set { Val =  value==0? null: value.ToString(); }
    }
}
```

output

```
Value: 0
json: {"Value":null}
```

Comment: I did. it's still the same error, did you try my fiddle? I need it to default to 0 or null on empty strings.

Comment: @RedLotus what is the error? Where did youi get the json you are trying to deserialize? It is radiciolus. Pls show the code to create this json

Comment: I'm asking about System.Text.Json..  I also said Json.net(Newtonsoft) handles that. I posted the url on my question. I'm asking how it will be done in System.Text.Json, I know it supports converters I'm just wondering if it has been done.

Comment: @RedLotus If you are looking for problems  you should select JavaScriptConverter then. It has more bugs then text.json

Comment: I'll just stick with Newtonsoft for now. It seems System.text expects same type JSON and doesn't do conversions as most forms in html default to empty strings. Also for empty string on datefields it throws an error as well. Newtonsoft converts those fields to the default or sets it to null if nullable.

Answer (score 0):

Add a JsonConverter: here is an example I used to convert an int. If the value read was anything except a int, it returned 0.

```
public class JsonInt32Converter : JsonConverter<int>
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return typeToConvert == typeof(int);
    }
    
    public override int Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        try
        {
            var value = reader.GetInt32();
            return value;
        }
        catch
        {
            return 0;
        }            
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, int value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Note: I didn't have to do writes for my program, so I didn't implement it.

Then just add it to your serializer options:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new JsonInt32Converter());
var myObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyObject>(jsonstring, options);
```